# Cisco Catalyst 3750 connected to Cisco ASA 5505 and dropping packets

Tags: firewall, cisco, vlan

(Cross posted from [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/315572) per suggestion there)

At the office, I have inherited a network that I am still trying to fully comprehend. I have a problem today with a new connection between:

- A port on a Cisco Catalyst 3750 [WS-C3750G-48TS-S running C3750-IPSERVICESK9-M version 12.2(53)SE1]
- A port on a Cisco ASA 5505 [ASA Software version 8.3(2)]

The 3750 is home to a Vlan that has a few ports assigned to it.

```
interface Vlan3
 description Internal network (172.18.160.0/24)
 ip address 172.18.160.1 255.255.255.0
```

I have a host (outside of my control) that needs to be in this VLAN (i.e it must have an address 172.18.160.something/24) that also needs to access the Internet.

To accomplish this, I ran a link from the Catalyst (Gi1/0/13) to the ASA (Ethernet 0/5). I configured the Catalyst port like so:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13
 description To ASA, 172.18.160.69
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
 speed 100
 duplex full
```

I configured the ASA like so:

```
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.18.160.69 255.255.255.0

interface Ethernet0/5
 speed 100
 duplex full
```

Then I plugged the host into Ethernet 0/4 on the ASA and instructed its owner to make its default gateway 172.18.160.69. I made a NAT rule in the ASA and set up some rules, and it's able to access the Internet without issue.

However, I noticed that the Catalyst reports a ton of packets being dropped toward the ASA.

```
Catalyst3750#show interfaces GigabitEthernet 1/0/13 | include counters|drops
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters 00:28:13
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 136909347
```

This is a huge number of drops, since there's not much traffic on this VLAN at all.

I tried these things:

- Make sure speed and duplex agree on both sides (100 Mbps / Full)
- Set `no cdp enable` on the Catalyst Gi10/13
- Set `no keepalive` on the Catalyst Gi10/13
- Checked for excessive CPU usage on both
- Checked for excessive traffic on both

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do the counters and traffic rates look like?

Comment: The ASA is the busiest in the VLAN- it's 134kbps in/502kbps out (from the Catalyst's perspective). The others are less than 5 kbps. None of the others have any drops recorded.

Comment: Are the drops increasing?  Those could be from a while back...

Comment: Yes, note above that I'd cleared counters 28 minutes before the snapshot. Clearing again shows another increase.

Comment: There is something I dont quite understand.. why is the host (assuming a PC) connected to Eth0/4 on the ASA instead of into the 3750?

Comment: pauska, mainly because it's in the rack with the ASA and not in the rack with the 3750.
Is there a reason why it wouldn't work though? Seems like a pretty straightforward layer 2 kind of thing.

Comment: I came to ask the same question as pauska.  I've looked twice and my eyes are tired, but I don't see anything in the configs above where your ASA knows anything about VLAN 3.  Also important in this is to understand the configs of the ports that connect the ASA to the 3750.

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking the physical media and any possible interconnects for damage.

Comment: An excellent suggestion. I'll feel very sheepish if this fixes it.

Comment: Nah... It happens.

Comment: No luck from changing to a known good cable, unfortunately.

Comment: You might have to consider looking closer at the hardware interfaces. Maybe by changing up the pairing with other equipment/interfaces for testing.

Comment: OK, so it wasn't that. One of the hosts in the VLAN was sending some multicasts. How the math of the 136909347 packets / 28 minutes works out given the traffic levels I saw, I have no idea. But shutting up that host seems to have solved the problem

Comment: Ok, so it was getting flooded. The multicast part is weird.